# I reinstalled Ubuntu, and I can't see my windows 8.1 anymore, where is my Windows files?

Tags: dual-boot, data-recovery, reinstall

Previously I unsuccessfully installed Ubuntu at the end of installation it told me that could install bootloader. So I loaded windows from my USB drive and decided to reinstall Ubuntu with out any options (In brackets it said that it will delete Ubuntu and install new one) I thought that would help with bootloader problem. The installation ended successfully without errors. However now Ubuntu works as my default operating system and I don't see my windows files anywhere?? Is there anyway to bring back windows or recover my files?? Were they deleted??

Please help, I have very important information on that hard drive without backup.

Comment: It is very unclear what you did. Please describe the process in as much detail as you can. I'd also advise not to use that computer for now in case you've overwritten your data. This way it'll be easier to recover if needed.

EDIT: Post a screen shoot of your partitions in Gparted please.

Comment: Just the pasted output from `parted -l` or `fdisk -l` would be as good & easier than a screenshot. And `lsblk` and `blkid` would show similar info too, maybe easier to read/interpret.

Comment: No you don't have any important data on your drive, otherwise [you would have made a back-up](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem, not with windows disappearing, but with it not longer booting.

To get Wiindows back (and for you to see if there is anything there to save) you will need to boot using your Windows installation media and start repair mode. If there is still a Windows partition it should find it and say it is on, e.g. d:\windows

For Windows7 - and from memory yesterday this was also for Windows8 (it has changed since XP (or Vista)).

Basically, once you are in repair mode AND it has found a Windows partition the commands you need to run (read what I ran yesterday and finally got my Windows7 back) are:

- Select command line mode
- enter bootrec twice as:

  - bootrec /fixboot
  - boot /fixmbr

Hope this helps!